# How does type conversion work if no content property is specified?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I already asked a similar question on *Programmers*, but did not receive a good answer.

Below is a quotation from the book **WPF4 Unleashed**:

> Plain text can often be used as the child of an object element, as in the
>       following XAML declaration of `SolidColorBrush`:
>
> `<SolidColorBrush>White</SolidColorBrush>`
>
> This is equivalent to the following:
>
> `<SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>`
>
> even though `Color` has not been designated as a content property. In this case,
>       the first XAML snippet works because a type converter exists that can convert
>       strings such as "White" (or "white" or "#FFFFFF") into a `SolidColorBrush` object.

If I understand correctly, `<SolidColorBrush>White</SolidColorBrush>` instantiates a single `SolidColorBrush` object thanks to the type converter. But how is the string `White` used? How does XAML know which property should get that value? What if there is another property of the same type as `Color`?

It's important to note that `SolidColorBrush` does not specify any content property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically a [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) is similar to a `ValueConverter`, with a `ConvertFrom` and a `CanConvertFrom` method among others. In the `CanConvertFrom` method, you are supposed to verify that the input value can be parsed into the correct `Type` for the `TypeConverter` (from the linked page):

```
public override bool CanConvertFrom(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Type sourceType)
{
    if( sourceType == typeof(string) )
        return true;
    else 
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
}
```

As you might expect, the `ConvertFrom` method is responsible for converting the `string` input value into the relevant object for the `TypeConverter` (from the linked page again):

```
public override object ConvertFrom(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
{
    if( value.GetType() == typeof(string) )
    {
        // Parses the string to get the integer to set to the property.
        int newVal = int.Parse((string)value);

        // Tests whether new integer is already in the list.
        if( !values.Contains(newVal) )
        {
            // If the integer is not in list, adds it in order.
            values.Add(newVal);
            values.Sort();
        }                                
        // Returns the integer value to assign to the property.
        return newVal;
    }
    else
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
}
```

There is a bit more to it than that, but you can discover what that is from the [How to: Implement a Type Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) page on MSDN.

> But how is the string White used?  How does XAML know which property should get that value?

The `TypeConverter` simply converts the `string` value into the object that is required by the relevant property... 'XAML' as you call it, knows that the `Background` property of a `Control` is of type `Brush` because that is the type of the `Control.Background` property. So it reads the value `White` and passes that to the type conversion system which looks to see if it has a registered converter that can convert between `string` and `Brush` and if it has, then it calls the methods of the relevant `TypeConverter` to convert the value.

---

UPDATE >>>

Having just re-read your question, it seems as though I may have got somewhat mislead by your title. It *could* be that you are actually interested in the [`MarkupExtension` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). From the linked page, the `MarkupExtension` class

> Provides a base class for XAML markup extension implementations that can be supported by .NET Framework XAML Services and other XAML readers and XAML writers.

Unfotunately, Markup extensions, which are essentially implementations of the Factory pattern, are far more complicated and out of scope for this website. However, you can find the complete story of Markup extensions in the [Markup Extensions and WPF XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

In short though, when a class extends the `abstract MarkupExtension` class, it has to override the `ProvideValue` method. This is the method that is responsible for generating the relevant property values from the input value, which is actually passed into the class via its constructor by the `XamlReader` that instantiates it.

You can find a good example of its implementation in the excellent [WPF Control Development Unleashed](http://www.adorkable.us/books/wpf_control_development.pdf) book on page 300.

Answer (score 1):

It does not need to know which property to set as it does not set one. It tries to find `TypeConverter` to convert `String` into new `SolidColorBrush` which in code would be equivalent to something like this:

```
var value = (SolidColorBrush)System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor
                              .GetConverter(typeof(SolidColorBrush))
                              .ConvertFrom("White");
```

what may confuse you is that `SolidColorBrush` is complex type but lets say you want to declare much simpler type like `Int32` so in XAML you declare namespace

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

and you write

```
<sys:Int32>1000</sys:Int32>
```

and it does not mean it will set some property of `Int32` but it will become `Int32`. WPF will try to find `TypeConverter` from `String` to `Int32`, which in this particular case most likely does nothing more then `Int32.Parse(...)` which in code would look something like this

```
var value = (Int32)System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor
                    .GetConverter((typeof (Int32)))
                    .ConvertFrom("1000");
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be mislead but I thought it did this via the `[ContentProperty]` attribute in that anything within an elements tags is determined to be the content and in the absence of any XAML markup is assigned to the property marked by this attribute

WPF/SL then looks at what type the content property is and continues the XAML parsing chain down to the children (in the case that you have XAML elements as content) or using the standard type converter for the determined content type

In this case the `ContentProperty` attribute must be set on the `Color` property of `SolidColorBrush`

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: `SolidColorBrush` does not have `ContentPropertyAttribute` and MSDN mentions nothing about `Color` property being decorated with any attributes besides `AttributeTargets` of `ContentPropertyAttribute` is set to `Class` so it cannot be applied to properties

Comment: Sorry, yes it's not applied to a property it's applied to a class but you do specify the property name in the `ContentPropertyAttribute` constructor, but it looks like this isn't the method that WPF uses for the above (as per your answer). I assume that `ContentProperty` comes into play in a subtly different scenario (i.e. when working with content control types rather than more simple types)